# Show account specific modules in php

Tags: php, access-control

I'm working on a site that has different types of user account - so someone could sign up as an artist, fan, or venue. Depending on the account type, I'd like to show different modules in the member dashboard area.

Using if statements seems quite messy, and I'm just wondering what other people's approach would be?

Comment: which cms or framework are you using?

Comment: I'm not at the moment, it's all custom

Comment: you can add a field for specifying user-type in users table in database. like 1-user,2-fan,3-venue....

Comment: But to show different modules in the Dashboard, I'd have to use a load of if statements?

Answer (score 0):

Use a ACL class, in which you record roles and access levels. Access levels could for instance be inheritable Then it's just a matter of

```
if(acl.isAllowed(user.getLevel(), "venue.events.edit")) {
   // ....
}
```

[This blog](http://ivangospodinow.com/zend-framework-2-acl-setup-in-5-minutes-tutorial/) lists an example using Zend Framework 2.